# How to make post request within php session?

Tags: php, session

Cannot make post request within session, can someone help?i copy from previously stack answers all of this), my php version is 7.3.11, when i launch this php and he just become blank and all, no any errors!

```
<?php
define("COOKIE_FILE", "cookie.txt");
session_start();


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


function httpPost($url, $data)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE); 
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

httpPost('myurl', array('ss'=>'ss'));
```

Comment: check apache error log or not ?

Comment: also add curl error code and debugging like : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar sure, no errors or warnings!

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar no error in curl

Comment: check error log or not ?

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar answer on your question is litle bit up!

Comment: linux - /var/log/apache2/error.log check this file for fatal or 500 or any error

Comment: Your `httpPost()` function returns whatever curl received.  You call that function, but you never do anything with whatever it returns.  Try `echo httpPost('myurl', array('ss'=>'ss'));`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic actually it does! cause in my case i don't need to do anything with it!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If your `curl` works, you will never see anything unless you `echo` it, as I describe.  If your curl fails, you should be looking at [curl_getinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php), and [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: @Don'tPanic i'm not dump, i understand that if i'm not echo it, i'm not see any details, but in my case i don't need it, all my code is right, and it done what i need!

Comment: Glad you worked it out.  Your question says `... he just become blank and all, no any errors ...`, so ...?  Sounds like you needed help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in you requests have some redirects(depth), so in that case use.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 10);
```

where 10 is max depth follow steps!